# 555 timer ciruit errors

Tags: 555, breadboard, debugging

I have set up a 555 Timer circuit on my breadboard following this diagram.[image: 555 Timer Circuit]

These are the values I use:

R1: 1k

R2: 1k

C: 0.1uf

Vcc: 9V

The only problem is, on pin 5, I have a 0.001uf capacitor.  When I connect the circuit, the led I have on pin 3 (normally I have an 8 ohm speaker but I wanted to see if any current was being produced) doesn't light up.  Here is a picture of my breadboard. (Sorry for the horrible wiring... And the extremely large image)

[image: Breadboard circuit]

The bigger capacitor is 0.1uf and the smaller is 0.001uf.  Also, wire colors don't mean a thing (again... sorry).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The resistor or led may not touch each other, I advise you double check your circuit with ohm-meter.

Comment: Does everything else look correct?

Comment: Did you do what I asked?

Comment: I don't have an ohmmeter

Comment: I'll buy one and try later, for now, I want to make sure my entire circuit is correct

Comment: Some solderless breadboards have a discontinuity in the middle of the power strips. I think this type doesn't, but it is worth checking.

Comment: Sure, I'll check, but do you think that I have a bad 555 since everything else seems correct. Also I found a multimeter, could that double as an ohm meter?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see from your picture: does the yellow wire go to pin 8 and the white wire go to pin 7?

The easiest way to troubleshoot this is to use your LED as a test light.

Disconnect the lead that goes from pin 3 and connect it to your +V rail.  Does the LED light?

Now take that lead and check pins 4 & 8.  Does the LED light?

Comment: I'll try that..

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to EE.SE.  Your circuit is reversed polarized, assuming that you have done this: 
**Red line = Vcc/positive**   **Blue line = ground**

First the LED, from the image you can see the flat side is connected to positive, flip it around and that should light up.

Second you need to switch pin 8 to positive and pin 1 to negative, then to make sure the 555 doesn't stay in reset put the pin 4 to positive.

Third R1 needs to be connected to positive and the 0.1uf should go to ground.
[image]

Comment: I will check my led polarity though

Comment: @irishpatrick I know the colours mean nothing, the large image helps to see the wiring though ;)

Comment: I checked my polarity, the blue line is vcc and red is gnd , I'll fix that

Comment: Ok then if it was like that your LED was origionaly reverse polarized, if you change power around ensure you change **IC connections**

Comment: How do I make sure that it doesn't stay in reset?

Comment: Pin 4 must be pulled HIGH to Vcc, I edited that in my answer it posted on its own halfway through.

Comment: So would leaving it connected to vcc work or would I have to use a pull up resistor

Comment: Straight to Vcc as in the schematic will work.

Comment: Pleasure, hope it works now ;)

Answer (score 0):

The schematic you provided can be found on http://www.robotix.in/tutorials/categ/auto/ic555 where it gives you the calculations for high and low times.

So, high time is \$T = 0.693 \times (R_1 + R_2) \times C\$. Replacing with your component values:

\$T = 0.693 \times 2 \times 10^3 \times 10^{-7} = 0.0001386\$ seconds.

And low time is \$T = 0.693 \times R_2 \times C = 0.693 \times 10^3 \times 10^{-7} = 0.0000693\$ seconds.

The frequency is about 4.8 kHz. You won't see the LED flickering at this frequency, but because high time is double than low time you should see it on all the time but at a lower intensity.

Double check the connections and the **LED polarity!**

Comment: I just checked the polarity, it all looks correct, do you think that I got a bad 555 and I should try a new one?